# If we use Negative Ions as probe for nuclear reactions, will they get deflected?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, nuclear-physics

I am studying the basics of Nuclear Physics, and just read about the Rutherford experiment.
My question is if we use Negative Ions as probe for nuclear reactions, will they get deflected?
If yes then why?
Because they should be attracted by the coulomb force.

Comment: They would also be repelled by the gold atoms electron cloud coulomb force at the same time...so it's a little more complicated

Answer (score 0):

Charged particles will be deflected by an electric field whether the force is attractive or repulsive.  Are you suggesting that an attractive force will not affect the path of a charged particle?